# Split/Explode a PHP String at 2 Different Places

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I have a string in PHP.

```
$str = "1.testone (off) 2.testtwo (off) 3.testthree (off)";
```

I need to split the string between the "." and the " (".

I know I can split the string at either the "." with:

`$str1 = explode('.', $str);`

This puts the string into an array with the array items being between the ".". Is there any way to make an array with the array items between the "." and " (", and either cut out the rest, or keep it in the array, but explode the string at 2 different spots.

Comment: what is your purpose of splitting 2 different places ? because regular expression can fit better for more complicated pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an explode in an explode, combined with a foreach loop.

```
$str = "1.testone (off) 2.testtwo (off) 3.testthree (off)";
$explode1 = explode('.', $str);
$array = array();

foreach($explode1 as $key => $value) {
$explode2 = explode('(', $explode1[$key]);
array_push($array, $explode2[0]);
}

print_r($array);
```

Produces:

> Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => testone [2] => testtwo [3] => testthree )

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $str = "1.testone (off) 2.testtwo (off) 3.testthree (off)";

    $result = preg_split("/\.|\(/", $str);

    print_r($result);
?>
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => testone 
    [2] => off) 2
    [3] => testtwo 
    [4] => off) 3
    [5] => testthree 
    [6] => off)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "1.testone (off) 2.testtwo (off) 3.testthree (off)";
$arr = array();
foreach(explode('.',$str) as $row){
    ($s=strstr($row,'(',true)) && $arr[] = $s;
}
print_r($arr);
//Array ( [0] => testone [1] => testtwo [2] => testthree )
```